# How can floatingActionButton be located at the right bottom in the screen

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to set floatingActionButton at the right bottom in my app.
[image: My test app]

My Activity.xml has a WebView and a FloatingActionButton with ConstraintLayout.

the code is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_back"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_back"
            android:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It should be android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"

Comment: @Venky , android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" doesn't work. so saaaaad.

Comment: You don't need that too if you have constraint layout as parent. Just set the constraint properly. So Gooooooood.....

Comment: @Venky , so saaaaaaad. it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to **delete** the line in your xml:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Then with margins you are good to go.